# Add a new colomn from value that is stored in a list of cell of the table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm quite new to powerbi developement, and I need your help.

I have a table build from a json :
[image]

And I want to add informations to this table, using data from the column "fille".
This cells are fill with 'List'

This 'List' are 'Record' :
[image]

And inside this record, I can find my information :
[image]

The field that I need is :

```
For each row of main table
    set the value "avancement" of the first 'Record' of the 'List'
```

How can I reach to do that ?

I'm trying somthing like this, without succes :

```
tableDev = Table.AddColumn(tableInfoFiltree, "Dev", each tableInfoFiltree[filles]{_}{0}[nom], type text)
```

I try also to build a function, but, the same, I don't reach to extract the List from the cell to put it in parameter.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
= Table.AddColumn(tableInfoFiltree, "Custom", each [filles]{0}[avancement])
```